# Can't change linewidth of a polyline i drew with drawnode,tried glLineWidth(),didn't work

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

i wanted to draw a polyline with DrawNode,it worked but i can't change line thickness and i used glLineWidth(),it didn't work.
and here is the code :

```
DrawNode *drawPayLineNode=DrawNode::create();
testSprite->addChild(drawPayLineNode,20);
Vec2 testPolyLine[5]={Vec2(300,300),Vec2(400,400),Vec2(400,500),Vec2(300,500),Vec2(200,400)};
glLineWidth(5.0f);
drawPayLineNode->drawPoly(testPolyLine,5,false,Color4F(223/255.0f,133/255.0f,231/255.0f,1.0f));
```

The version is V3.3 and the platform is windows.
Any help is appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw line with segment:

```
drawNode->drawSegment(startPoint, endPoint, LINE_WIDTH, color);
```

Next if you want to change line width, you have to clear the drawNode, and redraw line again with another width.

Comment: At first,i was trying to find a way to draw a polyline using some function once,but i failed.So i had to draw polylines consisting of many segments with drawSegment(),and it worked.Thanks anyway.